# Regex to match specific file names

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse some HTML of a directory listing page using c#.
That page has many file urls like "0220109_120548.046.jpg" but has also others like "0220109_120548.046-445x265.jpg". They are the same picture but one has its dimensions in the name.

I need a regex to match only the urls of those files without the dimensions.

I tried this one :
href="^"*.(gif|jpg|png)"

but its not working.

the regex101 url: https://regex101.com/r/APS9NY/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do so:

```
href=\"[^\"]*?(?<!\d{2,4}x\d{2,4})\.(gif|jpg|png)\"
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/LQpTPe/1) for the online demo.

---

- `href=\"`: Matches `href="`
- `[^\"]*?`: Any character that isn't `"`, between zero and unlimited times, as few as possible.
- `(?<!)`: Negative lookbehind.

  - `\d{2,4}`: Matches between 2 and 4 digits.
  - `x`: Matches `x`.
- `\.`: Matches `.`.
- `(gif|jpg|png)`: Matches either `gif`, `jpg` or`png`.
- `\"`: Matches `"`.

Comment: Good. This one works. But Iam going to make it not match the "href=" but only the file url itself;

Comment: @CaioMaia Just wrap the ``href=\"`` in a positive lookbehind and delete the last ``\"``: ``(?<=href=\")[^\"]*?(?<!\d{2,4}x\d{2,4})\.(gif|jpg|png)``.